# Update single field on Firestore database (cloud) with simple https request

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently using Swift (macOS) and that doesn't matter.

I can get my database data with this simple get request from Firestore

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/MY_PROJECT_NAME/databases/(default)/documents/" + "User_email" + "?pageSize=100&pageToken=" + "NextPage_Id"
```

Now I want to update one single filed on the database and I don't know how.

The Firebase API guide is too complicated for me and I don't understand it.

I found this get request URL:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{projectId}/databases/{databaseId}/documents/{document_path}?updateMask.fieldPaths=status&updateMask.fieldPaths=title
```

But when I try it, it gives me this  error:

```
 {
"details" : [
  {
    "fieldViolations" : [
      {
        "description" : "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"updateMask.fieldPaths\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'updateMask' could not be found in request message."
      }
    ],
    "@type" : "type.googleapis.com\/google.rpc.BadRequest"
  }
],
"code" : 400,
"message" : "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"updateMask.fieldPaths\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'updateMask' could not be found in request message.",


  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I Use above URL like this:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/MY_PROJECT_NAME/databases/(default)/documents/" + User_email + "/MY_COLLECTION_ID/?updateMask.fieldPaths=name&updateMask.fieldPaths=aaaa
```

Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally got the answer after getting help from FireBase support.

The request type must be PATCH, not POST or GET or anything else.

The request format must be "application/json"

The Body parameters type must be RAW data not form-data, for example:

```
["fields": ["finished": ["booleanValue": true]]] // this is the value you want to update
```

The url must be like this:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/\(VALUE_PATH)/?updateMask.fieldPaths=\(NAME_OF_KEY_YOU_WANT_TO_UPDATE)
```

for example:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/PROJECT_NAME/databases/(default)/documents/USER_EMAIL/4EJzurX9QWVnC1uG6sRv/?updateMask.fieldPaths=finished
```

Thats it.

Cool thing about this request is if the field you want to update does not exist, it will create one for you.

Comment: Used `{"fields": {"finished": {"booleanValue": true}}}` and it worked, thanks